# Laravel 5 - getting data to a view

Tags: laravel-5

I think this is slightly different to the usual controller passing data to the view.  I have a Project which **has one** DocumentOne.  Within my app, the user creates a Project.  This then redirects them to the show page for this project.

So with the project created, and the user on the show page for that project, I display the project ID.  I then provide a select menu where the user can select a Document to display.  So say I am in Project with the ID of 1, I then decide to show DocumentOne for this project.  This displays a form with inputs for DocumentOne.

When the user fills in the form and submits, the data is saved to the database.  The Project ID is the foreign key for DocumentOne.  The following route is set up for DocumentOne

```
Route::resource('projects.documentOne', 'DocumentOneController');
```

Now I have data for DocumentOne which is linked to the Project with an ID of 1.  However, if I now go back to the projects show page and then select Document One from the dropdown again, all I see is an empty form.  This is obviously because the controller for this is

```
public function show(Project $project)
{
    return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
}
```

So I am never passing it data for DocumentOne because theoretically it is not created when the Project is first shown.  What I want to do is when the Document is selected in the Projects show page, is to have the form populated with whatever is in the database for that Document.  If nothing is in the database, then the form will be empty.  I have a DocumentOne Controller, but I dont know if I can link this to the Projects show page.  I was thinking about doing something like this in the DocumentOne controller

```
public function show(DocumentOne $documentOne)
{
    return view('projects.show', compact('documentOne'));
}
```

But not sure this will work.  Hope I have not been too confusing and you understand what I am attempting, hoping someone can offer advice on how best to handle this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous project, I also deal with such requirement, I thought so. Here my solution to solve such requirement.

Actual code calling from ajax.

**Routes**

```
    get('setFlashData',function(Request $request){
        $final_response = array();
        $data_information = $request->except('_token');
        $request->session()->flash('cmg_quick_create_data', $data_information);
        if($request->session()->has('cmg_quick_create_data')){
            $final_response['result']['success'] = true;
        }
        return response()->json($final_response);
    });
```

But according to you requirement:

```
$data_information = $request->except('_token');
            $request->session()->flash('cmg_quick_create_data', $data_information);
```

My basic functionality was, to share form data from Quick Create Section which is pop-up form to Full create form section, and whenever user click to "Go To Full Form" button from pop up, ajax call mentioned function which will set the flash data and than on destination side I only check weather its contain the flash data or not. and deal according to data.

```
    @if (Session::has('cmg_quick_create_data')) {
        {!! Form::model(Session::get('cmg_quick_create_data'),["class"=>"form-horizontal","data-parsley-validate"=>"data-parsley-validate",'role'=>'form','files'=>true]) !!}
    @else
        {!! Form::open(["class"=>"form-horizontal","data-parsley-validate"=>"data-parsley-validate",'role'=>'form','files'=>true]) !!}
    @endif
```

I can understand this solution might be different from you requirement but hope full to figure out your solution. Look forward to hearing from you if still unclear from my side.